# Laravel 4 issues with php headers and returning downloads in controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm using KnpLabs Snappy PDF library to generate a PDF in Laravel 4. All works excellently when I explicitly put all my code in the routes.php file, but when I route to a controller and method my code no longer works? Am I missing something, or is there more I need to do if executing this code in a controller.

Route 'test1' works as expected, route 'test2' refreshes the browser and shows nothing, not even any errors.

**route.php**

```
<?php

Route::get('test1', function()
{
    $pdf = new Knp\Snappy\Pdf('/path/to/vendor/google/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/wkhtmltopdf-amd64');
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="file22.pdf"',
    );
    return Response::make($pdf->getOutputFromHtml('<h1>Works!</h1>'), 200, $headers);
});

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'trial'), function()
{
    Route::get('test2', 'MyController@download');
});
```

**MyController.php**

```
<?php

class MyController extends \BaseController {


    public function download()
    {
        $pdf = new Knp\Snappy\Pdf('/path/to/vendor/google/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/wkhtmltopdf-amd64');
        $headers = array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="file22.pdf"',
        );
        return Response::make($pdf->getOutputFromHtml('<h1>Works!</h1>'), 200, $headers);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try doing "echo hello" in your download() function and comment out the rest of the code - do you even see that text?

Comment: Nope, neither `echo 'hello';` or `return 'hello';` work. But I have found the problem as stated in my answer below.

Comment: Just a small tip: Response::download(); exists. http://laravel.com/docs/responses#special-responses

http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Support.Facades.Response.html#69-87

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**. For some reason the contents of the `download()` method doesn't work if it's being specified in either a `Route::resource()` or a `Route::group()`.

When I explicitly state the route on it's own all works fine.

Like this: `Route::get('trial/test2', 'MyController@download');`

I've got no idea why this is, but if anyone else can shed some light on the reasoning behind this, I'd be very interested.

Comment: I'd call that a solid bug - very strange indeed.

Comment: You need to specify the HTTP verb to use. In your case, try renaming your method to getDownload(). Check their docs about it: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that you need to (sometimes?) specify the url with a leading slash:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'trial'), function()
{
    Route::get('/test2', 'MyController@download');
});
```

although official documentation states/suggests otherwise.

Might be something to do with Laravel app config but didn't get time to investigate this further.